# C# WinForms combobox not displaying text when selected index is set

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have something curious happening with a winforms combobox.

Note: this is not databound - I populate all controls from a datatable.

I add a list of account numbers to the combobox and then display a set of records in a grid that are keyed on the combobox text value.

I can add account numbers, change between the account numbers, all works fine.

If I delete an account number from the box, I delete the account number and all associated records from the db. That works fine.

I then repopulate the combobox from the remaining values in the accounts table and set the SelectedIndex to 0 in order to set it to the first Account Number in the list.

```
if(cboAccountNumbers.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        cboIBAccountNumbers.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

I then make a call to the db to fetch the records keyed on the combobox.Text value - which works - there is a text value, and it is correct, and data is returned.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = DataUtils.GetRowsByAccountNumber(cboAccountNumbers.Text);
```

However, when the form regains focus, the combobox text is blank.

If I click on the dropdown, the correct items are there - however, the text associated with item index 0 is not showing as the combobox text value.

Any suggestions as to what is up?

```
private void cboAccountNumbers_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteAccountNumber(sender, e);

    }

private void DeleteAccountNumber(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
        {
            ComboBox cbo = (ComboBox)sender;

            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this Account?\n\n" +
                                              "All strategies related to the account will be deleted as well.",
                                              "xxx",
                                              MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
                                              MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                using (PgSQLDb db = new PgSQLDb())
                {
                    // two things to do - delete intersection table values between 
                    // ib_account_numbers and strategies i.e. ib_account_numbers_vs_strategies
                    // then delete the account number itself

                    // 1. delete account_numbers_vs_strategies
                    db.Delete("account_numbers_vs_strategies", " account_number_id = (select id from account_numbers where acc_number ='" + cbo.Text + "')");

                    // 2. delete account_numbers record
                    db.Delete("account_numbers", "acc_number = '" + cbo.Text + "'");
                }

                GetAccounts(string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

private void GetAccounts(string account)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = DataUtils.GetAccountNumbersTable();

        string selectedItem = string.Empty;

        cboAccountNumbers.Items.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            cboAccountNumbers.Items.Add(row["acc_number"].ToString());
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["is_default"]))
            {
                selectedItem = row["acc_number"].ToString();
            }
        }

        // if an AccountNumber is passed in, use that (typically when a 
        // new account is created)
        // else use the default 
        // else use first item in list.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(account))
        {
            cboAccountNumbers.SelectedItem = account;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedItem))
        {
            cboIBAccountNumbers.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
        }
        else
        {
            if(cboAccountNumbers.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                cboAccountNumbers.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }            

        GetStrategies();
    }


private void GetStrategies()
    {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            string selectedItem = cboAccountNumbers.Text;

            dt = DataUtils.GetRowsByAccountNumber(selectedItem);

            gvwMain.Rows.Clear();
            strategies.Clear(); // list of Strategy objects

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                Strategy cd = new Strategy(Convert.ToInt16(row["strategies_id"]),
                                            row["name"].ToString(),
                                            Convert.ToBoolean(row["active"]),
                                            Convert.ToDecimal(row["percentage_of_portfolio"]),
                                            Convert.ToInt16(row["margin"])
                                            );
                strategies.Add(cd);
            }

            gvwMain.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            BindingList<Strategy> bindingList = new BindingList<Strategy>(strategies);
            BindingSource source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
            gvwMain.DataSource = source;
            gvwMain.Refresh();
            FormatGrid();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show complete code please

Comment: We will need more code about how you set the items to de cb.

Comment: Is it a normal combobox, or an user defined? Did you try to call Invalidate() after the selection change?

Comment: Have you tried handling the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and putting a breakpoint there? The call stack might reveal the problem.

Comment: Meister Schnitzel: normal combobox, no didn't call Invalidate().

Comment: C.Evanhuis - nothing strange in call stack

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are referencing two different combo boxes: cboAccountNumbers and cboIBAccountNumbers.

Your local string 'SelectedItem' is being used on cboIBAccountNumbers so cboAccountNumbers will never get that value as it's selecteditem.